# How to test @Invocable SendEmail method

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I have a flow that calls an invocable method that sends emails.

**My class** :

```
public class SendVerificationEmailAction {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Send Verification Email' category='Email' description='Send Emails to users to verify their email address')
    public static void sendEmail(List<FlowInput> inputs){
        for(FlowInput inp: inputs){
            System.UserManagement.sendAsyncEmailConfirmation(
                inp.userId, 
                inp.emailTemplateId, 
                inp.networkId, 
                inp.landingPageUrl
            );
        }
    }
    
    public class FlowInput{
        @InvocableVariable(required=true) public Id userId;
        @InvocableVariable public Id emailTemplateId;
        @InvocableVariable public Id networkId;
        @InvocableVariable public String landingPageUrl;
    }   

}
```

---

How can I test sendEmail method ?

Comment: You test invocable methods like you test any other method - just call it from your unit test, with necessary inputs. The trick here is to not actually call the `UserManagement.sendAsyncEmailConfirmation` method in the unit test since this probably cannot be successfully invoked from a unit test. You need to either use `if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {` condition around it or otherwise ensure the send doesn't actually happen when in a unit test. It isn't always possible to get 100% test coverage because of these sorts of limitations.

Comment: what I would do is move the call to `System.UserManagement.sendAsyncEmailConfirmation` into a service class; then inject a mock service class into your testmethod and use ApexMocks to verify you call the mock class x times where x is the same as `inputs.size()` and each call to the mocked service matches the expected arguments. I don't think the service class itself is testable as the email can't be sent